# How to get one level in XML by linq

Tags: xml, linq

I have an XML

```
<item id="1">
    <item id="1.1">
        <item id="1.1.1" />
        <item id="1.1.2" />
        <item id="1.1.3" />
    </item>
    <item id="1.2" />
</item>
<item id="2">
    <item id="2.1" />
    <item id="2.2" />
    <item id="2.3" />
</item>
<item id="3" />
```

I need LINQ to get the first level, without children

```
<item id="1" />
<item id="2" />
<item id="3" />

or for item="1"

<item id="1.1" />
<item id="1.2" />

or for item="1.1" 

<item id="1.1.1" />
<item id="1.1.2" />
<item id="1.1.3" />
```

I build a menu, where I need to receive just nest level items.

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an `XElement`, you can call the `Elements()` method to get its direct children.  (You can ignore the grandchildren)